# Show desktop notifications on Windows with Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows

is there a way to display desktop notifications on Ruby when something happened? Something like `notify-send`. I saw one gem to do this with Ruby but I'm not sure if it works on Windows. Do I have to explicitly use C# to do this on Windows?